# Error while copying Word tables to Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, excel-2016

I am trying to copy a table from Microsoft Word 2016 to Microsoft Excel 2016 but not been very successful.

I get an error

```
User-defined type not defined
```

in this section of code below :

```
Public Sub ImportTableDataWordDoc(ByVal strDocName As String)
```

Could anyone help me with this, please?

The entire code follows:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportTableDataWord()
Const FOLDER_PATH As String = " \User\kritikata\Desktop\Articulateexporteddata\"

Dim sFile As String

sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & " *.docx ")

If sFile = " " Then
    MsgBox " The file is not present or was not found "
    Exit Sub
End If

ImportTableDataWordDoc FOLDER_PATH & sFile
End Sub


Public Sub ImportTableDataWordDoc(ByVal strDocName As String)

Dim WdApp As Word.Application
Dim wddoc As Word.Document
Dim nCount As Integer
Dim rowWd As Long
Dim colWd As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo EH

If strDocName = "" Then
    MsgBox "The file is not present or was not found"
    GoTo FINISH
End If

Set WdApp = New Word.Application
WdApp.Visible = False

Set wddoc = WdApp.Documents.Open(strDocName)

If wddoc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No document object"
    GoTo FINISH
End If

x = 1
y = 1

With wddoc

    If .Tables.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Tables Found in the document"
        GoTo FINISH
    Else

        With .Tables(1)
            For rowWd = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For colWd = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(rowWd, colWd).Range.Text)
                    y = y + 1
                Next 'colWd
                y = 1
                x = x + 1
            Next 'rowWd
        End With

    End If

End With

GoTo FINISH
EH:

With Err
    MsgBox "Number" & vbTab & .Number & vbCrLf _
        & "Source" & vbTab & .Source & vbCrLf _
        & .Description
End With

'for debugging purposes
Debug.Assert 0
GoTo FINISH
Resume
FINISH:

On Error Resume Next
'release resources

If Not wddoc Is Nothing Then
    wddoc.Close savechanges:=False
    Set wddoc = Nothing
End If

If Not WdApp Is Nothing Then
    WdApp.Quit savechanges:=False
    Set WdApp = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Write on the line before the error `MsgBox strDocName`  and share the result.

Comment: Could you please be a bit clear, write where exactly? @Vityata

Comment: on the line before the line with the error.

Comment: Sorry just want to clarify! Do you mean to write MsgBox strDocName before the line with the error? If yes, which error line.

Comment: Write it on the line before `ImportTableDataWordDoc FOLDER_PATH & sFile`.

Comment: So, I wrote 'MsgBox strDocName' before the 'ImportTableDataWordDoc FOLDER_PATH & sFile' and it says variable not defined.

Comment: Write `MsgBox FOLDER_PATH & sFile` instead

Comment: Thanks, @Vityata but the message box shows the only Path of the file and doesn't show the exact .docx file.

Comment: Then you start realizing where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & " *.docx ")` does not get the correct docx file.

This is visible, if you write `MsgBox FOLDER_PATH & sFile` before calling the sub.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. Trying to debug and understand why the sFile doesn't trace the exact file. Need to change the code I suppose.

Comment: @KritikaR - if you know the name of the exact file and it never changes, write this `sFile = FOLDER_PATH & "the_name_of_the_file.docx"` and everything would be quite nice.